# Infinite while loop while counting binary gap

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I'm currently working on solving the binary gap problem (counting the number of 0's between two 1's, and returning the largest gap of 0's found), my solution first starts off with converting the integer N into a string of N's binary form, which works fine.

Conceptually what I'm doing (or at least think I'm doing) was counting the 0's until I reach a 1 character, which is then compared to the current count of 0's under the variable `gap`, I then would zero out my zero counter `zero_count`, and I also added an if statement to check for the case of it reaching the end of the binary string, returning 0 if no and 1 if found.

For some reason I'm getting an infinite loop, and I think I've narrowed it down to the index value not incrementing, and I'm not sure why. If someone could explain I would greatly appreciate it!

This was done in Java.

```java
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int N) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        String binary = "";

        int power = 31;

        //double expo = Math.pow(2,power);
        while(power !=-1){
            if(N - Math.pow(2,power) > -1){
                binary += "1";
                N -= Math.pow(2,power);
            }
            else{binary += "0";}
            power--;
        }
        System.out.println(binary);
        
        //above works
        int  gap = 0;
        int zero_count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
            if(binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
                index= i+1;
                while(binary.charAt(index) =='0'){
                    index++;
                    zero_count++;
                    if(index == binary.length()-1){
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(zero_count > gap){
                gap = zero_count;
            zero_count = 0;
            }
            i = index;
        }
        return gap;
    }
}
```

Comment: The binary of 31 is 00011111, so you can ignore `if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')` and `if(zero_count > gap)`, now think: will your loop ever exit? Then you'll understand the issue.

Comment: I see the mistakes now but one question but am still confused about whiy I'm getting an infinite loop, should the index variable increment repeatedly at this portion? 
 if(binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
                index= i+1;
                while(binary.charAt(index) =='0'){
                    index++;

Comment: Only if it goes inside that if and the infinite loop shows that it doesn't. Like I said, ignore both ifs and then think about how your remaining code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many loops..

added main to drive/run the code; you can remove the static on the method.

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("the max gap is: "+ Solution.solution(103241));
        }

    
    public static int solution(int N) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        String binary = "";

        int power = 31;

        //double expo = Math.pow(2,power);
        while(power !=-1){
            if(N - Math.pow(2,power) > -1){
                binary += "1";
                N -= Math.pow(2,power);
            }
            else{binary += "0";}
            power--;
        }
        System.out.println(binary);
        
        //above works
        int  max_gap = 0;
        int zero_count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        //boolean 
        for( int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
            if(binary.charAt(i) == '0') {
                zero_count++;
            }
            else {
                if (zero_count > max_gap){
                    max_gap = zero_count;
                }
                zero_count = 0;
            }           
        }
        return max_gap;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code counts consecutive zeroes, which may happen as a prefix or suffix while only the zeroes between `1`  should be counted, e.g. for `0` 32 zero gap is returned, for `1` - 31 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the nested `while` loop:

- it should check for the length of `binary` when comparing a character at `index` to avoid `StringOutOfBoundsException`
- it should not return `0` when reaching the end of the string - the result can be incorrect
- `index` should be decremented upon leaving the `while` loop
- leading `0`s should be skipped altogether to avoid infinite loop
  Also, there are issues with building `binary` string:
- it does not convert negative numbers properly
  That being said, the following code resolves the mentioned issues:

```java
public static int solution(int N) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    String binary = "";

    if (N == 0) {
        binary = "0"; // shortcut for 0
    } else {
        N &= Integer.MAX_VALUE; // remove sign bit for negative numbers
        while(N != 0) {
            binary = (N & 1) + binary; // get rid of leading zeros
            N >>= 1;
        }
    }
    
    //above works
    int gap = 0;
    int zero_count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0, len = binary.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            i++;
            while (i < len && binary.charAt(i) == '0') {
                zero_count++;
                if (i == len - 1) {
                    zero_count = 0;
                }
                i++;
            }
            i--;
        }
        if (zero_count > gap) {
            gap = zero_count;
            zero_count = 0;
        }
    }

    return gap;
}
```

However, a simpler solution may be implemented using the following facilies available in Java 8:

- `Integer::toBinaryString` to get a binary string without leading zeroes
- `String::replaceAll` to remove trailing zeroes
- `Pattern::splitAsStream` to split the remaining string by `1` and get `Stream<String>`
- common Stream API `mapToInt`, `max` to get the maximal length of substrings consisting of zeroes only:

```java
static int maxZeroGap(int n) {
    return Pattern.compile("1")
        .splitAsStream(
            Integer.toBinaryString(n).replaceAll("0+$", "")
        )
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .max()
        .orElse(0);
}
```

Tests:

```
int[] nums = {
    0, 1, -1, -1023, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0b10, 0b11, 0b101, 0b1001, 0b100101, 0b101000, 0b1000000100001
};
for (int i : nums) {
    System.out.printf("%d -> %s%n", i, Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    int z = maxZeroGap(i);
    System.out.println("max zeros = " + z + "; solution=" + solution(i));
    System.out.println("--------------------");
}
```

Output

```
0 -> 0
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
1 -> 1
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
-1 -> 11111111111111111111111111111111
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
-1023 -> 11111111111111111111110000000001
max zeros = 9; solution=9
--------------------
-2147483648 -> 10000000000000000000000000000000
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
2 -> 10
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
3 -> 11
max zeros = 0; solution=0
--------------------
5 -> 101
max zeros = 1; solution=1
--------------------
9 -> 1001
max zeros = 2; solution=2
--------------------
37 -> 100101
max zeros = 2; solution=2
--------------------
40 -> 101000
max zeros = 1; solution=1
--------------------
4129 -> 1000000100001
max zeros = 6; solution=6
--------------------
```